WSL can connect to VM, but not the other way around
I'm on Windows 10 and I have a service running on WSL2 Ubuntu and another service running on a Ubuntu Server VMWare VM, and although WSL can access the VM, the service on the VM seemingly can't connect to WSL.
I'm on a work computer with Zscaler, but all features are off.
WSL IP: 172.17.202.100
WSL Host Interface:
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.192.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

VM IP: 192.168.64.132
VM Host Interface:
Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.64.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

WSL reaches VM:
inet 172.17.202.100/20 brd 172.17.207.255 scope global eth0

~$ ping 192.168.64.132
PING 192.168.64.132 (192.168.64.132) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.64.132: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.517 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.64.132: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.661 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.64.132: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.484 ms
^C
--- 192.168.64.132 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2049ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.484/0.554/0.661/0.076 ms

~$ tracepath 192.168.64.132
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  172.17.192.1                                          0.315ms
 1:  172.17.192.1                                          0.437ms
 2:  192.168.64.132                                        0.724ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 2 back 2

VM doesn't reach WSL:
inet 192.168.64.132/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.64.255 scope global dynamic ens33

~$ ping 172.17.202.100
PING 172.17.202.100 (172.17.202.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 172.17.202.100 ping statistics ---
19 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 18435ms

~$ tracepath 172.17.202.100
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  no reply
 2:  no reply
 3:  no reply
^C

The service inside the VM runs on Docker, and initially I thought the problem was a conflict with dockers subnet ip range, which was the same as the WSL (172.17...), but since then I changed the Docker bridge IP and Container IP to IP Range (182.17 and 182.16), but didn't seem to matter.
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    inet 182.17.1.1/16 brd 182.17.255.255 scope global docker0
4: br-b650f316942d: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    inet 182.16.1.1/24 brd 182.16.1.255 scope global br-b650f316942d
    inet6 fe80::42:2dff:fe23:d49a/64 scope link

Any ideas? I've been on this for 2 days and completely ran out

You're trying to reconcile many networks. This is not impossible, just very complicated. My advice would be to simplify it to the limit. For example, with this answer you could unify Windows and WSL2.

Thanks @harrymc, didn't think of that, I will try that out!

I saw that option in the past, remembered now, but that config is only available in Windows 11, I'm running 10 :(

Windows 10 is approaching EOL, might be time to upgrade.
